# MySQL: Select row from table which name is specified in a field of another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a `feed` table with say fields:

- `id` - unique feed id
- `created` - the date the feed was created
- `table`  - the name of the table the rest of the feed info resides

Then I have say 2 tables: `feed_image` and `feed_text`. Now these 2 tables contain different information about a feed, different fields.

How is it possible (in MySQL) to extract the information for the feed from the appropriate table which name is specified in `feed.table`?

Here is how my schema looks like:

```
                                                 +------------------+
                                                 |    table_a       |
      +---------------------+                    |------------------|
      |   feed              |                    | id               |
      |---------------------|             +------+ feed_id          |
      |  id         <-------------------+-+      | field_in_a       |
      |  created            |           |        | ...              |
      |  table              |           |        |                  |
      |                     |           |        |                  |
      |                     |           |        |                  |
      |                     |           |        +------------------+
      +---------------------+           |
                                        |
                                        |
                                        |        +-------------------+
                                        |        |   table_b         |
                                        |        |-------------------|
                                        |        |  id               |
                                        +--------+  feed_id          |
                                                 |  field_in_b       |
                                                 |  ...              |
                                                 |                   |
                                                 |                   |
                                                 |                   |
                                                 |                   |
                                                 +-------------------+
```

Each feed exists either in table_a or table_b or table_c or ... (I have like 30 of them).
How can I specify which table to extract the info from (each table has a different structure).

Or, if I add indexes on each `table_*.feed_id` and map it to `feed.id`, would InnoDB do some magic, so when I JOIN them all it would look in just one of them, not all 30?

My latest idea is to have just one table `feed` with a field `feed.content` where I would store a serialized PHP object of a different PHP class representing the different feed type and its individual contents.

What is the best way to go regarding performance?

P.S.: No records would need to be selected / searched / ordered by individual parameters, just by `created`. The idea should be able to work well with 1 000 000+ records.

UPDATE:

To clarify about the 30+ table_a/b/c..

Each feed can be of too many different types (new ones will also be added with time):

- An image feed would have VARCHAR(255) `url` field
- A text feed would have LONGTEXT `text` field
- A youtube.com feed would have VARCHAR(255) `title`, VARCHAR(255) `video_id` fields
- A *.com feed would have * `x1`, * `x2`, * `x3` ... fields

Each of these feeds will be then displayed with PHP according to type:

- An image will be displayed as na image from the given URL
- A text will be displayed as a pure text
- A youtube.com feed would display a video player with the given title from the given video id
- A *.com feed would display... :)

Comment: Can't do it with a regular query, but you could do a stored procedure which dynamically builds a query and executes that.

Comment: I suppose that might work, but I'm more concerned about performance..

Comment: Do you have control over the structure of the database?

Comment: Yes, it is running on my localhost, so - full control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a LEFT JOIN and alias my columns in the select and alias my tables in the join allowing you to return any and all information you need.

The with whatever language your pulling the results you can group and perform logic as necessary.

UPDATE:

Why do you have 30 tables exactly? Maybe one "meta" table with the feed creation date url it came from etc... and another table that contains a unique record id, feed id, content, content type.

That way you can join on one table where feed id's match as well as group by or filter by content type.

Visualization: Feed table

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  feed_id   | feed_name  |  feed_created     |   Feed_url   |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     1      | Feed 1     |  03/28/2012       |  www.go.com  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     2      | Feed 1     |  03/28/2012       |  www.be.com  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     3      | Feed 2     |  03/28/2012       |  www.hi.com  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     4      | Feed 3     |  03/28/2012       |  www.ex.com  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Visualization: Feed Resources table

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   rec_id   |  feed_id   |     content                                         |    type      |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     1      |      1     | 'hello world!                                       |    text      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     2      |      3     | 'http://me.com/my-image                             |     img      |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     3      |      2     |{\'title\':\'VIDEO\',\'url\':\'http://me.com/1.mov\'}|     vid      |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     4      |      1     | 'Wow that was easy!'                                |     text     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Yes, it is going to work with JOINs, but here's the catch, I could have 30 different tables with content and for each row I want to search the rest info in just one of them, not all..

Comment: so why dont you strip your rows with the feedID and place a where clause?

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not understand that.. My schema is exactly as @d_inevitable draw it.

Comment: I will have 30+ tables becouse feeds will REALLY vary in types. For example: 1) An image feed has `url`, 2) A text feed has `text` 3) A youtube.com feed has `title`, `embed_code` 4) A *.com feed has `x1`, `x2`, `x3` fields..

Comment: Ok I would still do it this way, maybe serialize your content that has multiple attributes.

Comment: Updated with visualization. Hope it helps

Comment: Serialization, that is my favorite idea so far :)

Answer (score 2):

Can't you do something like this:

```
                                                     +------------------+
                                                     |    table_a       |
          +---------------------+                    |------------------|
          |   feed              |                    | id               |
          |---------------------|             +------+ feed_id          |
          |  id         <-------------------+-+      | field_in_a       |
          |  created            |           |        | ...              |
          |                     |           |        |                  |
          |                     |           |        |                  |
          |                     |           |        |                  |
          |                     |           |        +------------------+
          +---------------------+           |
                                            |
                                            |
                                            |        +-------------------+
                                            |        |   table_b         |
                                            |        |-------------------|
                                            |        |  id               |
                                            +--------+  feed_id          |
                                                     |  field_in_b       |
                                                     |  ...              |
                                                     |                   |
                                                     |                   |
                                                     |                   |
                                                     |                   |
                                                     +-------------------+
```

And then join the records from `table_a` and `table_b`? MySQL is pretty efficient at that.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need, but the rest of 1 feed's info is located in just one table_a/b/c.. and there are like 30 of them, woudn't this join walk them all for each row?

Comment: Hmm, i think you could do something with innodb tables and foreign keys. But not much a db expert. (by that i mean that you can have the above structure and innodb will add some innerworking date for this association, but that is just theory)

Comment: If I map feed_id in each table to the original feed id maybe InnoDB could do some magic.. but I don't know how I could test such a thing.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps somebody can confirm that theory. I suggest you update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a normalized layout as d_inevitable suggested.

You haven't told us exactly how you're displaying this data.  But you can get a list of ALL feeds with select * from feed;

Then you can get additional data for the feed by searching the other tables.  For your example of URLs, if table_a = URLs and field_in_a = URL

Whichever feed you're on, you'd search for URLs with the ID for that feed.
select * from URLs where feed_id = "id"
This would allow each feed to have 1 to many URLs associated with it.
You could do this for each type of data you'd have associated with a feed.  The "feed_id" is your Foreign Key that you use to reference which feed it is.

The key is going to come down to how you're displaying this.
You're going to need to loop through all the Feeds, and then build a table (?) appropriately.

If a feed has two URLs, how do you want it to look?

Should it display

```
-------------------------------------------------
| Feed Name  |  Feed Created     |   URL        |
-------------------------------------------------
| Feed 1     |  03/28/2012       |   www.go.com |
-------------------------------------------------
| Feed 1     |  03/28/2012       |   www.be.com |
-------------------------------------------------
| Feed 2     |  03/28/2012       |   www.hi.com |
-------------------------------------------------
| Feed 3     |  03/28/2012       |              |
-------------------------------------------------
```

or

```
-------------------------------------------------
| Feed Name  |  Feed Created     |   URL        |
-------------------------------------------------
| Feed 1     |  03/28/2012       |   www.go.com |
|            |                   |   www.be.com |
-------------------------------------------------
| Feed 2     |  03/28/2012       |   www.hi.com |
-------------------------------------------------
| Feed 3     |  03/28/2012       |              |
-------------------------------------------------
```

I think the data layout should be as d_inevitable suggested, and then you need to determine how you're going to display the data, and that will determine how you query it.

Comment: Check my original question, I've just updated it with examples of the different feeds.

Comment: You don't specify which table to search in.  You'd search them all.
You'd do a `select * from table_n where feed_id = "id"` and if it returns 0 rows, you don't have any data for that feed.  I wouldn't store WHICH types of data you have.  Whichever type of data you're looking for, you search that date, if no rows are returned, you don't have any of that type of data for that feed.

Comment: So for each feed, you'd search through all 30 tables, and if you get rows, you have data for it.  If you don't, you don't have data.  
If you're concerned about searching through all 30 tables and getting 0 results back, you could create an additional table (feed_data) with feed_id and datatype.  This table could contain each additional table you have data in.  A feed_id could exist 0 to many times in this table.  Then you could query feed_data where feed_id = "id" and you'd have rows for each table you'd expect to find data in.

Comment: You seem very concerned about "magically" linking tables and data together.  I don't understand why?

Comment: I'm not concerned, it was just and idea @d_inevitable gave, I still don't uderstand your idea though. Think of it as PHP classes, there is one base parent and many children with different fields extending it. Only one child (no matter what type) could extend a single parent. I need to get all rows, but each will have individual fields according to the child that represents it. That is why I thought I might approach it through the parent rather than walking all types of children..

Comment: A database isn't an object oriented, parent-child relationship.

Comment: You have a master table that contains all of your feeds.  The other tables contain data about that.  Don't think of it as parent-child.  If we use people as an example.  You'd have a master table of people.  It'd include your unique id, and name.  Then you'd have a table for cars, with the person that owns it and the car name.  A person could own 0 to many cars.  We'd have another table for computers, a person could own 0 to many computers.  A single person can have 1 car and 2 computers.  So they'd have 1 row in the Person table, 1 rows in the cars table, and 2 rows in the computers table.

Comment: You may want to read up on Database normalization, some articles may explain it better than I am. 
[link1](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/dataNormalization.html)
[link2](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/2nf.htm)

Comment: The issue with TimWickstrom.com 's is storage.  If you're looking at one million plus records, you could be wasting a lot of DB space.  A DB table has to allocate storage for the LARGEST amount of space you could use.  Which is why you'd generally want to put each type into a separate table.  I guess depending on how large this all gets and exactly how you store the data, it could eventually become a performance problem.

Comment: Also, you may want to store different things.  Lets say on an image you want to know uploaded date, but you don't care about that for a URL.  You'd have a blank field on all your rows that aren't an image type.
That solution will work.  With any problem, many solutions WILL work.  But it isn't the best way of doing it :-)